# How to set HTTP_REFERER header in a Django view?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to explicitly set the `HTTP_REFERER` header of a request in a Django view, over-riding the browser? I tried `self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') = '/example/uri/here/'` but it's erroneous. My guess is this isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.META` is a dictionary, so you simply do:

```
self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER'] = '/example/uri/here/'
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Note that the original header will contain the domain.

Comment: You're right. The only reason setting this artificially occurred to me is certain really ancient clients (think old-school feature phones) on my network throw up errors when I do `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` in my code. Their browsers are probably incapable of setting that. So I thought maybe I could do a `try` `except` and set this myself? I'd say around 10% people on my network have this problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that sounds like a separate question to me.

Comment: Yea it is a separate question; just trying to get a feelsky. As for the answer to the asked question, that's indeed complete. I'll mark it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In your view's `response`, you can [set or modify HTTP header fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields):

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['REFERER'] = '/example/uri/here/'
return response
```